# Outer class attributes not passing to inner class Attributes for python inheritance

Tags: python, function, class, inheritance

I don't really know what I have done wrong here. I get the error "student has no attribute name" when it gets to the output data function. Any ideas are greatly appreciated.

```
class Person: 
    def __init__(self):
       self.ID=""
       self.name=""
       self.address=""
       self.Phone_number=""
       self.email_id=""
       self.student=self.Student()
       
    def read_data(person):
        person.ID=input("please enter ID:")
        person.name=input("Please enter name:")
        person.address=input("Enter address:")
        person.Phone_number=input("Enter Phone Number:")

    class Student:
        def __init__(self):
            self.class_status=""
            self.major=""
        
        def read_data(student):
            student.class_status=input("Enter class status:")
            student.major=input("Enter student major:")
        
        def output_data(student):
            information=(student.name + " " + student.ID + " " + student.address + " " + student.Phone_number + " " + student.class_status + " " + student.major + "\n")
            print(information)
            studentFile.write(information)

def StudentDetails(): 
    person=Person()
    person.read_data()
    student=person.student
    student.read_data()
    student.output_data()

studentDetails()
```

Comment: Why are you nesting classes? That is generally not what you would do. It doesn't really give you anything, and makes things more unwieldy.

Comment: "I have to have the nested classes for assignment so just making them separate will not work." Are you *certain* you have interpreted your instructions correctly? I suspect not, because that would be highly unusual. What exactly do your instructions say? Are you sure this wasn't meant to be *inheritance*? Because that would make more sense given the standard `Person`/`Student` inheritance example one would see in a typical CS class

Comment: I was wrong I am supposed to be using an inheritance relationship, I guess My lack of knowledge kind of assumed they are the same. My apologies.

Comment: No need to apologize, it is a common misunderstanding when learning about inheritance. That's why I asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The attributes of an outer class aren't passed to an inner class. It looks like you're trying to model an inheritance relationship, which you can do by using subclassing rather than nesting classes. For example, you could do something like the following:

```py
class Person: 
    def __init__(self):
       self.ID=""
       self.name=""
       self.address=""
       self.Phone_number=""
       self.email_id=""
       
    def read_data(person):
        person.ID=input("please enter ID:")
        person.name=input("Please enter name:")
        person.address=input("Enter address:")
        person.Phone_number=input("Enter Phone Number:")

class Student(Person):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.class_status=""
        self.major=""
    
    def read_data(self):
        super().read_data()
        self.class_status=input("Enter class status:")
        self.major=input("Enter student major:")
    
    def output_data(self):
        information=(self.name + " " + self.ID + " " + \
          self.address + " " + self.Phone_number + " " + \
          self.class_status + " " + self.major + "\n")
        print(information)

def studentDetails(): 
    student = Student()
    student.read_data()
    student.output_data()

studentDetails()
```

If you are absolutely sure that you must use a nested class, then the relationship you're trying to describe doesn't make sense. I could see something like a student ID class being an inner class of Person to store some additional attributes, but I don't think the relationship as currently described makes much sense.

Comment: You are definitely right that I am trying to do an inheritance relationship, I was just on the wrong track. I am trying to get your code to work right now but I am still having some troubles, still working though.

Comment: It seems that when I do exactly this it only prints out class_status and major with a few spaces before. I assumed then that I needed to add my "person" so I did student=Student(person) but this gives me the error"__init__ takes 1 positional argument 2 were given. Any ideas?

Comment: In a subclassing relationship, you don't need to pass the superclass (or any instances of it) to the subclass. Use `student = Student()` instead.

Comment: When I do that is when it ends up printing "      status major" not any of the attributes from person, just their initialized values.

Comment: Are you using the exact code described in my answer?

Comment: Yes It is all the same.

Comment: I have updated the question with my updated code incase there is something I am possibly overlooking.

Comment: Try this new code; I'll rollback your original edit since it isn't tied to the original question.

Comment: Happy to help. Before you go, you might want to read the third-to-last and second-to-last bullet points under "Asking about homework" [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions). Long story short, we're here to help people learn, not to faciliate academic integrity infractions. If you're going to use any part of this code in a submission for a course, make sure you understand what you use and make sure you give attribution as appropriate. Good luck!